# Doxygen conditional compilation does not produce documentation

Tags: doxygen, conditional-compilation

I'm a relative beginner with doxygen, and am documenting a C program

Part of the code is:

```
\#include "options.h"
// options.h contains
\#define VAL0 0   // Possible values for PARAM
\#define VAL1 1
\#define PARAM VAL0

// Here's the conditional compilation
\#if (PARAM == VAL0)
// code chunk, which doesn't get compiled by Doxygen
\#endif
```

The code compiles with GCC as expected, but I get no Doxygen documentation

OK, Doxygen doesn't expand macros, so I tried:

```
\#define SYMEQ(A, B) (A == B) ? 1 : 0

\#if SYMEQ(PARAM, VAL0)

// code chunk

\#endif
```

Set the Doxygen:

MACRO_EXPANSION = YES

EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES

No Predefined macros

EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = SYMEQ

No doxygen output from the conditional part, just up to it

I also tried EXPAND_AS_DEFINED SYMEQ(A, B)

Also no luck

I found a few examples with simple names, then #ifdef NAME \code #endif, but none with macro functions

Answer (score 3):

I just had the problem `#ifdef CONDITION \code not compiled by doxygen\ #endif` and fixed it by brute force, i.e, appending the conditions to the setting `PREDEFINED=CONDITION1 CONDITION2 ...` manually.

I tried the header file solution -- generate a file with conditions and include it by setting `SEARCH_INCLUDES`, `INCLUDE_PATH` and `INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS` -- but it did not work. From the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enable_preprocessing), I think it requires to explicitly `#include "the condition file"` in the source files, which means to modify the source code, so I give up.

> **SEARCH_INCLUDES:**
>   If the SEARCH_INCLUDES tag is set to YES (the default) the includes files in the INCLUDE_PATH (see below) will be searched if a #include is found.

Comment: Adding the include paths was hit the spot. This is done by enabling `SEARCH_INCLUDE` option and then adding the paths to `INCLUDE_PATH` list.

Answer (score 1):

`MACRO_EXPANSION` and `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` only control whether a macro will be expanded in your code, not how it will be evaluated in conditional preprocessor blocks.  For example, if you had code like:

```
#define RET_TYPE int

/**
 * Some function
 */
RET_TYPE func(void);
```

With `MACRO_EXPANSION=NO`, this will be documented by doxygen as `RET_TYPE func(void)`, the macro isn't expanded. With `MACRO_EXPANSION=YES`, this will be documented as `int func(void)`, the macro is expanded and the resulting signature is documented.

To control conditional code, you'll want to focus on the `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING`. If this option is set to `NO`, conditional code will be ignored, and all code within the condition will be documented. If it is set to `YES`, the conditional code will be evaluated, and only blocks for which the condition matches will be documented. In this case, you'll need to make sure that all of the values being evaluated are defined correctly, this can be accomplished by allowing doxygen to evaluate include files (see `SEARCH_INCLUDES`, `INCLUDE_PATH` and `INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS` options), or by predefining the macros to have a particular value (see `PREDEFINED`).